# Is the below command valid in python?

Tags: python

Is the below command valid in python ?

```
if(os.path.isfile("file path") && os.path.isfile("another file path") )
```

Comment: Why don't you open the IDLE and try it out?

Comment: you mean `and`, not `&&`.

Comment: no, && is not valid syntax

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a yes/no question that is not going to be useful for anyone else.

Comment: i want to check weather both file exists in system or not,, How Do i do that?

Comment: @Sunny: Why didn't you ask that in the first place? However, in that case I would recommend to read a tutorial, to learn the basics: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-conditions

Comment: @Felix :I read it but still didn't answer my question ?

Comment: *"Comparisons may be combined using the Boolean operators `and` and `or`, and the outcome of a comparison"*

Comment: Thanks.. I will use this.. :
if(os.path.isfile("file path") and  os.path.isfile("another file path") )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this valid Python?:

```
if(os.path.isfile("file path") && os.path.isfile("another file path") )
```

No, && isn't valid syntax, and you require a colon for the next code block. However, this would be (and would be better style):

```
if os.path.isfile("file path") and os.path.isfile("another file path"):
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if os.path.isfile("file path") and os.path.isfile("another file path"):
    do something
```

would be the correct syntax for your question.